# What is the purpose of using `TaskCompletionSource` here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task

From C# in a Nutshell

> The following example prints 42 after waiting for five seconds:
>
> ```
> var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
> new Thread (() => { Thread.Sleep (5000); tcs.SetResult (42); })
>   { IsBackground = true }
>   .Start();
> Task<int> task = tcs.Task;         // Our "slave" task.
> Console.WriteLine (task.Result);   // 42
> ```

What is the purpose of using `TaskCompletionSource` here?

Can it be rewritten equivalently without `TaskCompletionSource`?

For example, is it equivalent to the following? If not, what are the differences between them?

```
Task<int> task = Task.Run (() => { Thread.Sleep (5000); return 42; });
Console.WriteLine (task.Result);   // 42
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its only purpose seems to be demonstrating something that the book is talking about.  Nobody really writes code like this.

Comment: As an FYI, you should never use `Thread.Sleep` in a `Task`, uses `Task.Delay` instead.

Comment: @Hans Thanks. What difference does it demonstrate?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks. why?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is a blocking operation, `Task.Delay` is an asynchronous one

Comment: ["a way to retain the Task façade and the ability to refer to an arbitrary asynchronous operation as a Task"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/02/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks. What does that mean, for example, in the case of my post?

Comment: Your post is a piece of code that demonstrates this feature. In an artificial way. The Thread is the 'arbitrary asynchronous operation' and tcs is the Task to consume it.

Comment: @Henk Is `Thread.Sleep (5000);` part of the work  done by `tcs.task`?